# Fixed width div on left, fill remaining space with input box on right

Tags: html, css

I'm well and truly stuck. I've gone through a lot of other topics on here with similar problems and lost count of how many different things I've tried but nothing seems to be doing the trick...

I'm making a comments section, and want the users profile picture to display on the left, with a text box filling the remaining space along side it... I've obviously managed to get it working with fixed width div's, but I'd rather not do that.

HTML:

```
<div class="feed_comments_comment">
    <div class="feed_comments_picture"> 
        <a href="#"><img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=25" style="width: 25px;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="feed_comments_add">
        <input type="text" class="feed_comment" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.feed_comments_comment {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}
.feed_comments_picture {
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    background: blue;
}
.feed_comments_add {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.feed_comments_add input {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXMGB/1)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `calc`:

http://jsfiddle.net/sXMGB/3/

```
.feed_comments_add {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

[IE9+](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: hah, now I feel suitably stupid for not knowing you could do that... this is going to help a lot in future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try a table:

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="feed_comments_comment">
<tr>
    <td class="feed_comment_picture"><a href="#"><img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=25"/></a></td>
    <td class="feed_comments_add" align="right"><input type="text" class="feed_comment" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.feed_comments_comment
{
    background: red;
}

.feed_comments_picture
{
    background: blue;
    width: 25px;
}

.feed_comments_picture img
{
    width: 25px;
}

.feed_comments_add
{
    background: green;
    width:100%;
}

.feed_comments_add input
{
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: You need width 100% on the input.